# Additional question of 9.13 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Firstly, I have the same question about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573388/theorem-9-13-in-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis).

The last line of the proof is completely proved if we show that (i) $||f||_2=||f^\vee||_2$ for all $f\in L^2$ and (ii) $f=(f^\wedge)^\vee $, neither of which is to be understood from the answer in the above link.

Above all, the second half of Ch 9 of the textbook is devoted to preparing for the ingredients of this theorem, and all ingredients are about the usual Fourier transform, not the inverse Fourier transform. Thus, I cannot understand how the answer in the link can so easily generalize the statements of the theorem to the case of the inverse Fourier transform. I can hardly believe. Should we prove the last line only in this way? Or, is there another way that is much more understandable? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familliar with the book so I don't understand the problem. But why not everywhere you see $F^{-1}f$, just use $F(F(F(f)))$ or $F^{-1}f(x) = Ff(-x)$?

Comment: @Calvin Khor I actually tried in both ways, but they are just seemingly working at the beginning, but do not work after all.

Comment: (ii) follows just by definition of $F^{-1}$, because $F^{-1}$ is the inverse transform. The inverse exists because of (c). Then (i) follows by applying (ii) to (b). This is from the answer, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks, your reply resolves the question. I has been confused due to the inverse Fourier transform formula expressed in explicit integral form for elements in L^1. I can just ignore this explicit form, and just denote the inverse mapping as F^{-1} as you mentioned, then all are resolved at once. Deriving an explicit formula for the inverse mapping, if at all (I don't know whether it is, and the textbook does not deal with it), is another thing and out of point here, but I has been obsessed with it, which stopped me from thinking naturally.

Comment: Glad to help! in fact part (d) gives an explicit (limit) formula for the inverse FT as an operator on $L^2$. (d) does not imply that the integral definition that works for  $f\in L^1$ also works on $L^2$.

Comment: @Calvin Khor Sure. Thanks a lot.