# Plancherel Theorem in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (theorem 9.13)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, fourier-transform

I understood the whole theorem proof, except for the very last part.

Here is the theorem

> **9.13 Theorem** One can associate to each $f\in L^2$ a function $\hat{f}\in L^2$ so that the following properties hold:
>
> (a) if $f\in L^1\cap L^2$, then $\hat{f}$ is the previously defined Fourier transform of $f$
>
> (b) for every $f\in L^2\quad,\quad||\hat{f}||_2=||f||_2$
>
> (c) The mapping $f\rightarrow \hat{f}$ is a Hilbert space isomorphism of $L^2$ onto $L^2$.
>
> (d) The following symmetric relation exists between $f$ and $\hat{f}$ : If $$\varphi_A(t)=\int_{-A}^{A}f(x)e^{-ixt}dm(x)\quad\text{and}\quad\psi_A(t)=\int_{-A}^{A}\hat{f}(x)e^{ixt}dm(x)$$ then $||\varphi_A-\hat  f||_2\rightarrow 0\quad\text{and}\quad||\psi_A-  f||_2\rightarrow 0$

The part I miss is the last (d) dealing with $\psi_A$ ; Rudin wrote "The other half of (d) is proved the same way" (with no detail at all: the "first half" deals with $\varphi_A$).

One answer that I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573388/theorem-9-13-in-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis) assumes that the following function $\mathscr F^{-1} : L^1\rightarrow L^\infty$ is the inverse Fourier transform  $$\mathscr F^{-1}(f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{ixt}dm(x)\qquad\qquad(\star)$$

But in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", the inversion theorem (9.11) gives this formula only when the function and its Fourier transform are in $L^1$ :

> 9.11 **The Inversion Theorem** If $f\in L^1\quad\text{and}\quad \hat f\in L^1$ and if $$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat f(x)e^{ixt}dm(t)\qquad (x\in R^1)$$
> then $g\in C_0\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=f(x)$ a.e.

If $k_A$ is the characteristic function of $[-A,A]$, then $\psi_A$ seems to be the inverse Fourier transform of $k_A\hat f$, assuming that the inverse Fourier transform is given by $(\star)$.

"Seems to be" : this is exactly the point I miss : although obviously $k_A\hat f\in L^1$, nothing proves that $\psi_A$ is in $L^1$ (I daresay the contrary, since generally $k_A\hat f$ is not equals a.e. to a continuous function, whereas the Fourier transform of a $L^1$ function is coninuous), so Rudin's 9.11 theorem can't be applied.

Hence my question : how can this "second part of (d)" be resolved ?

Comment: How does Rudin prove the first part of d), since he says that the other part is proved the same way?

Comment: The proof for the first part is this :
with $k_A$ the characteristic function of $[-A,A]$ then $\varphi_A$ is the Fourier transform of $k_Af$ since $k_Af\in L^1$.

Also, $$||k_Af-f||_2\rightarrow 0\quad\text{when}\quad A\rightarrow +\infty$$

As the Fourier transform is linear and isometric, this shows that $||\varphi_A-\hat f||_2\rightarrow 0$ when $A\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: I agree that the proof is incomplete. If we denote by ${\cal F}$ the Fourier transform and denote ${\cal R}(f) (x) = f(-x)$, it is clear from Rudin's arguments that $\psi_A$ converges to ${\cal R F F}(f)$ and that ${\cal R F F}$ is an isometry in $L^2$. To conclude, one only needs a dense subspace of functions $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ such that $\hat{f}\in L^1\cap L^2$, because on this subspace, ${\cal R F F} = Id$ by Theorem 9.11. The Schwartz space could be this subspace for example.

Comment: I also thought about this, although I know little about the Schwartz space.

However, there must be another way, for Rudin states in the next theorem (9.14) the fact that $\cal R\cal F\cal F=Id$ : $$\text{If}\quad f\in L^2\quad\text{and}\quad \hat f\in L^1\quad\text{then}\quad f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat f(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)$$ Also, it seems that plancherel proves this theorem in 1910, five years before L. Schwartz was born.

Comment: The subspace doesn't have to be the Schwartz space, for example you could take the linear span of the functions of the form $g * h_\lambda$ where $g\in L^2$ and $g$ has compact support, and $h_\lambda$ is defined in paragraph 9.7. I think it is an exercise to prove that this subspace is dense in $L^2$ and satisfies the required properties. Theorem 9.10 will be helpful.

Comment: @Gribouillis How do you prove that $\psi_A$ converges to $\mathcal{RFF}(f)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ {\lambda}  >  0$, let

\begin{equation}{h}_{{\lambda}} \left(x\right) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{{\pi}}} \frac{{\lambda}}{{{\lambda}}^{2}+{x}^{2}} , \qquad  {H}_{{\lambda}} \left(t\right) = {e}^{{-{\lambda}} \left|t\right|}\end{equation}

as in Rudin's paragraph 9.7. It is easy to check that

\begin{equation}{\hat{h}}_{{\lambda}} = {H}_{{\lambda}} , \qquad  {\hat{H}}_{{\lambda}} = {h}_{{\lambda}}\end{equation}

Now we have the following

**Lemma A:** if $ g \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$ and $ {g}_{{\lambda}} = g \ast  {h}_{{\lambda}}$ then $ {g}_{{\lambda}} \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$ and
$ {\hat{g}}_{{\lambda}} \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$.

Indeed, by theorem 9.10 in Rudin we have $ {g}_{{\lambda}} \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$ (see also exercise 8.4)
and by theorem 9.2, we have $ {\hat{g}}_{{\lambda}} = \hat{g} {H}_{{\lambda}}$, but
$ \hat{g} \in  {C}_{0} \subset  {L}^{\infty }$ (theorem 9.6) and
$ {H}_{{\lambda}} \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$.

**Lemma B:**
The set
$ X = \left\{g \ast  {h}_{{\lambda}} \  \mid  \  g \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2} , {\lambda}  >  0\right\}$ is dense in $ {L}^{2}$.

Indeed, let $ f \in  {L}^{2}$ and $ {\varepsilon}  >  0$.
There exists $ A  >  0$ such that $ {\left\|{f}_{A}-f\right\|}_{{L}^{2}}  <  {\varepsilon}$
where $ {f}_{A} = f\, \mathbf{1}_{\left[{-A} , A\right]}$. We have
$ {f}_{A} \in  {L}^{1} \cap  {L}^{2}$ and by theorem 9.10, there exists some
$ {\lambda}  >  0$ such that $ {\left\|{f}_{A} \ast  {h}_{{\lambda}}-{f}_{A}\right\|}_{{L}^{2}}  <  {\varepsilon}$. Hence $ {\left\|{f}_{A} \ast  {h}_{{\lambda}}-f\right\|}_{{L}^{2}}  <  2 {\varepsilon}$ and $ {f}_{A} \ast  {h}_{{\lambda}} \in  X$.

Let $ {\Phi}$ be the Fourier transform defined on $ {L}^{1}$ and also on $ {L}^{2}$ by the density argument given by Rudin in the
proof of parts a) b) c) of theorem 9.13, and let $ \mathcal{R}$ be
the mapping $ \mathcal{R} \left(f\right) \left(x\right) = f \left({-x}\right)$.

It is clear that $ \mathcal{R} {\Phi} {\Phi} \left(f\right) = f$ for every function $ f \in  X$ because by lemma A, these functions satisfy
the conditions of theorem 9.11. As $ \mathcal{R} {\Phi} {\Phi}$ is an isometry
of $ {L}^{2}$, the relation $ \mathcal{R} {\Phi} {\Phi} \left(f\right) = f$ extends to
all $ f \in  {L}^{2}$ by continuity.

Now in the proof of part d) of theorem 9.13 we have that
$ {\left\|{{\psi}}_{A}- \mathcal{R} {\Phi} {\Phi} \left(f\right)\right\|}_{{L}^{2}} \rightarrow  0$, which proves the result
since $ \mathcal{R} {\Phi} {\Phi} \left(f\right) = f$.

Comment: How do you prove that $\|\psi_A - \mathcal{R}\Phi\Phi(f)\|_{L^2} \to 0$ as $A\to\infty$?

Comment: @LordVader Rudin proves that $\|\varphi_A - \Phi(f)\|_{L^2}\to 0$, but $f$ is an arbitrary $L^2$ function. If you apply this to $\hat{f}$ instead of $f$, you get $\|{\cal R}\psi_A - \Phi(\hat{f})\|_{L^2}\to 0$, but this norm is also $\|\psi_A - {\cal R}\Phi\Phi(f)\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this relation implies theorem 9.14 in Rudin? It says that if $f\in L^2$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1$, then $$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)\quad a.e.$$

Comment: @LordVader By definition,$$\psi_A(x)=\int_{-A}^A\hat f(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)$$ and by proof $$\lim_{A\rightarrow+\infty}||\psi_A-f||_2=0$$ Also, since $\hat f\in L^1$,$$\lim_{A\rightarrow+\infty}\psi_A(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat f(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)$$
If you name $$g(x)=\lim_{A\rightarrow+\infty}\psi_A(x)$$ then $||g-f||_2=0$ hence $(g-f)(x)=0\quad\text{a.e.}$ This proves that $$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat f(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)\quad\text{a.e.}$$

Comment: @LordVader also Theorem 3.12 tells you that a subsequence of $\psi_A$ converges almost everywhere to $f$, but as hdci said above, if $\hat{f}\in L^1$, then $\psi_A$ converges pointwise everywhere to the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ by the Lebesgue theorem.

Comment: @Gribouillis Can you tell me some reference where I can find such Lebesgue Theorem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LordVader Here I mean the dominated convergence theorem. The functions $\hat{f} \mathrm{1}_{[-A, A]}$ satisfy the conditions of this theorem. In Rudin it's theorem 1.34.